# Peltier behaves strangely

Tags: voltage, current, parallel, peltier

I've been trying to test my Peltier moodule (tec1-12706) with 2 1.3V batteries (2.6 in total in series) connected parallel to the module..

```
|+ -| ------|Peltier +|                                          
|- +|-------|Module  -|
```

The batteries are full and show 2.6 volts.
But when I measure the voltage drop on the Peltier it shows only 2 V and it draws only 200 mA max (according to [TEC1 12706 datasheet](http://www.thermonamic.com/TEC1-12706-English.pdf) it should draw 1 A.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are your batteries capable of supplying 2 A? (A datasheet for the battery would be helpful)

Comment: Not knowing your level of experience I have to also ask, 1. How did you measure the TEC current? 2. What kind of heat sink did you use on the hot side? 3. How much heat is the thermal load on the cold side producing? A photo of your setup would be helpful.

Comment: 2 batteries of 1.3V each connected **in parallel** will give 1.3V only!

Comment: @JimmyB *The batteries are full and show 2.6 volts* ... they should "show" 1.3 volts if it were the case.

Comment: I'm sorry it was a little confusing, the batteries are in series and the whole source unit is connected in parallel to the module

Comment: Did you have any heatsinks or thermal measurements? were both batteries exactly equal?

Comment: If your meter reads 2.6V for 2 unloaded batteries and reads 2.0V for the same batteries at a 200mA load, it would appear your batteries each have 1.5\$\Omega\$ internal resistance.

Comment: What type of battery is 1.3V nominal?